# Wrong time inside Unity coroutine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I use coroutines for my animation work. And I must be sure that timings are perfect. For example I need to increase value overtime.I set time and stepCount to perform this. My code looks like this:

```
IEnumerator ScaleDown(float time)
{
    print(Time.time);
    float value = 0f;
    float deltaValue = 1 / (stepCount*time);
    float deltaTime = 1/stepCount;
    while (value < 1f)
    {
        value += deltaValue;
        meshRenderer.SetBlendShapeWeight(1, value * 100f);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(deltaTime);
    }
    print(Time.time);
}
```

So when I set time=1f and stepCount=1 then real time between start and end print are 1 second.
But when I increase stepCount to 100 or more keeping time=1, then real time is more then 1 second.
Something about ~1.67f

So I have question: How can I use coroutines with specific stepCount and have perfect timing? I use stepCount for more smooth transition on blenshapes, shader variables like opacity. And must use stepCount>=100.

Comment: You could try and use `WaitForSecondsRealtime` instead. However note that if in that frame it comes to a lag due to heavy calculation then ofcourse it might take a bit longer to update that frame .. could this be the reason maybe? Note that it makes no sense to make `yield return WaitForSeconds` for values smaller then the actually framerate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I use stepCount for more smooth transition on blenshapes, shader variables like opacity. And must use stepCount>=100.

These steps shall all happen in `1` second ... **but**:

Your code runs with a certain **framerate** optimal about `60 f/s` (on a PC and within the editor mostly higher) which results in a "standard" `Time.deltaTime` of about `0.017 seconds` between two frames!

```
yield return new WaitForSeconds(XY);
```

or in general **anything** using `yield` waits **at least for one frame**!

So of course your functionality breaks as soon as `deltaTime` becomes smaller then the actual possible framerate and real time between two frames. Especially for example when you say you want this to be executed `>=100` times per second.

It also makes no sense to update a value more often then the framerate since no changes will be ever noted by the user faster then the frames are actually rendered.

Additionally `SetBlendShapeWeight` might be a performance intense call (don't know to be honest) so it might also slow down the execution causing additional lag.

---

> How can I use coroutines with specific stepCount and have perfect timing

Beyond a certain limit you just can't.

But why do you need/want to use fixed steps for the `value` **at all**?

Since `value` is a `float` and what it seems you actually want is rather a smooth transition you could simply do

```
IEnumerator ScaleDown(float duration)
{
    print(Time.time);
    timePassed = 0f;
    do
    {
        // a linear interpolated value between 0 and 1
        var value = timePassed / duration;
        // optionaly you could even add some ease-in and ease-out
        //value = SmoothStep(0, 1, value);

        meshRenderer.SetBlendShapeWeight(1, value * 100f);

        // increase by the time passed since last frame
        // to avoid overshooting use Mathf.Min with the remaining difference
        // between duration and passedTime
        timePassed += Mathf.Min(duration - timePassed, Time.deltaTime);
        yield return null;
    } while (timePassed < duration);
    print(Time.time);
}
```

I you still want to fake it the other way round and make it update in fixed steps for `stepCount` < framerate you could simply round the smoothly transitioned values to that value like e.g.

```
value = Mathf.Round(value / deltaValue)) * deltaValue;
```

which should round up or down to the next full step of `deltaValue`.

---

Also note that in [newer Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SkinnedMeshRenderer.SetBlendShapeWeight.html) versions the `SetBlendShapeWeight` is **not** automatically limited to the range `[0; 100]` anymore as it was in [previous versions](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/SkinnedMeshRenderer.SetBlendShapeWeight.html).

Though, most 3D modelling programs export models with the range `[0;100]` in Unity

> The BlendShape weight range includes values between the minimum and the maximum weights defined in the model.

Comment: `WaitForSeconds` will always wait until *at least* the next frame, even if `t` is 0. This is  true for all `yield` statements.

Comment: @Draco18s yes thanks for the info .. makes sense actually since `yield` is called at least once anyway.

Comment: Thank you) Very informative and I knew something new)